# Grails 2.0, Resource Plugin and root hosting

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I've been upgrading a Grails 1.3.7 project to Grails 2.0.  Everything was going smoothly until I hit integration (first non-local deployment).  The gist of the problem is that it appears the Resource plugin always prepends the app name to the static CSS/JS URLs it generates, regardless of the grails.serverURL or grails.app.context specified for the environment.  What's strange is image resources are hosted with the appropriate URL "/static/foo.png" but CSS/JS files attempt to be served as "/AppName/static/foo.js".  Tracking this issue in ResourceTagLib, this initially looks like a issue in Resource Plugin but I don't want to jump to conclusions.

Our integration environment is setup with Apache proxy passing all traffic from "/" to ":8080/AppName" hosted on Tomcat.  Therefore, all traffic to "http://int.sitename.com" is hitting the app running on Tomcat.  Previously, in 1.3.7, grails.serverURL="http://int.sitename.com" was all that was required to get resources to served correctly.

Does anyone know a way to resolve this issue or does this look like a bug present in Resource plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Grails 2.0 too. There is a line `app.context=/` in the `application.properties`. As application is deployed to Tomcat, it's also on renamed to ROOT.war on deployment, so Tomcat will use a ROOT ie / context for this application. As result I don't have the described issue.

Comment: Thanks.  Going this route fixed things up.  Didn't realize some legacy code in the original app was rewriting URLs and causing my headaches.  Set everything to Root and the world is happy.